# Warning the selected directory is not a valid tomcat home

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I installed Tomcat with home brew `brew install tomcat`. On Selecting Tomcat server to add a server to the application server I get this

> Warning the selected directory is not a valid tomcat home.

However, running `catalina start` starts the tomcat server on my terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step 1.**

Download the `tomcat` with the tar.gz extension. 
**NB.** The `tar.gz` extention

**Step 2.**

Unzip the file and make sure the folder name remain `tomcat`, save it to your library.

**Step 3.**

Access the preference settings on your intellijIDEA

- Under Build, Execution and Deployment, select application server.
- Attempt to add a new server, click `+` and select `Tomcat Server` from the drop down.
- Click on the `...` elipse to select the folder you have unziped earlier into your library.
- select the `tomcat` folder and boom.

You are good to go, ready for use.

Comment: Step 1 must like as "Download the core version of Tomcat 7 here. DO NOT INSTALL IT WITH APT-GET OR ANY PACKAGE MANAGER"

Answer (score 31):

If you are using **IDEA on Linux platform**, use the command:

`chmod 755 -R apache-tomcat-<<Your-tomcat-version>>`

Then try to restart your service again.

Comment: `chmod 755 -R tomcat-dir` is fine enough! Never give 777-rights to anything!

Answer (score 22):

Try selecting the `libexec` subdirectory in IntelliJ - i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.9/libexec`

Answer (score 20):

**Problem:**

[image]

This happens because intellijIDEA doesn't have enough permission
to read and write on the tomcat home folder, this happens on linux machines.

**Solution**

let your tomcat root folder = "/opt/tomcat"
then this command which will set the right privilege level for intellijIDEA.

$ sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/tomcat

[image]

Comment: Works for Ubuntu + requires to restart IntelliJ. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This recently came up for me on Ubuntu 17.04

What worked for me

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat8
rmdir lib/
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat8/lib/ .
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/ .
```

I'm not sure this is the best fix but it worked for me.  For some reason the default install left the tomcat8/lib directory empty while the real libraries are under the share directory.

Answer (score 1):

I did what CallmeSurge suggested, except I had to change the following:

**Step 3: Create a new Tomcat Runtime Configuration**

- Select the Runtime Configurations box (top right hand corner of the screen), and select Edit Configurations.
- Select the green + sign at the top left corner of the box.
- Select Tomcat (you may have to expand the box to see it)
- Give your new configuration a name
- In the Server tab, in the Application Server box, select the tomcat folder you created in steps 1 and 2.
- In the Deployment tab, select the build artifact you want to deploy. (Note: if you don't have a build artifact configured for your project, you'll have to configure one first).
- Save the new configuration.

Now, deploying to tomcat is as easy as selecting the runtime configuration you just created and hitting the Debug or Run arrows.

Answer (score 1):

**Authorise permissions on Tomcat folder**:

- Open tomcat location e.g. C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
- Double click this folder.
- Authorise permissions.

Now try creating the server...

Answer (score 1):

There may be a situation where the folder will be inaccessible to the user due to lack of rights. Try to open the root folder of Tomcat and click OK to get rights to it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I just executed Intellij as administrator and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

During the Apache install, you must to remove all spaces in the home directory path :

C:\Program Files\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat_9.0

Save your Intellij configuration, close and re open the Tomcat Runtime Configuration.