# Tomcat server setting with Intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I searched about how to set Tomcat as my project's server but still haven't figured out so let me ask you why.

I have Tomcat but get error message which say "the selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home".

**Question**

Can you suggest reasons why I might get this message?

[image]

Comment: Here is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055786/warning-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-tomcat-home) that can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tomcat \[Ubuntu\] - Warning: The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601691/tomcat-ubuntu-warning-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-tomcat-home)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to select a subdirectory of your current directory, which contains tomcat executables.

In my case it was /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.32/libexec

[image]

Comment: the OP uses Windows, as you can see in the path (D:\...). It seems you're using OS X ...

Comment: I am aware of that. It is just for illustration, the point of my answer was to point to dir with tomcat executables.

Comment: Confirmed working on Mac OS.  For anyone googling an ending up here (after installing tomcat via brew) this information is still very useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because your user account associated with IntelliJ doesn't have permission to read the folder.

Once you grant access, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, in my case it was because I downloaded the zip from the `src` folder from the tomcat archive (https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.50/src/), and being on a windows, what I actually needed was the windows64 zip from the `bin` folder (located in my case on this link : https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.50/bin/, and the file I needed was `apache-tomcat-7.0.50-windows-x64.zip` )

Downloading the "right" tomcat zip and extracting the files fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

So for me, under Windows, the fix was super easy - i've removed spaces and added underscore in the main app folder (so Apache Software Foundation) and in Tomcat folder directly

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1

C:\Program Files\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat_10.1
```

Hope it help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with Idea 2023.3 new configuration.
Setting the permission wasn't enough for me.
I simply added a **"\"** at the end.

**From**

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat xx.x
```

**To**

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat xx.x\
```