# tomcat [Ubuntu] - Warning: The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have installed Tomcat 9 in my PC (on Ubuntu 16.04).

[image: Tomcat path]

I also successfully started the server in port 8080.

[image]

The problem is, when I try to configure Intellij IDEA to run a Tomcat server, it throws the following error:

[image: Intellij IDEA Tomcat path error]

I don't know what the problem with the `Tomcat home: opt/tomcat` is since i have no other tomcat folder on my PC, and as shown, it works perfectly. I have tried putting inner `opt/tomcat` folders, like `Tomcat home: opt/tomcat/bin` or `Tomcat home: opt/tomcat/lib` (where executables are), but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012414

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA supports the standard Tomcat layout for the official distributions from https://tomcat.apache.org. OS specific distributions installed by the package managers may have non-standard layout. We recommend to download and use the official distribution. At least you can compare it to what you have to find out what's missing or located in a different place.

Also check that you have the current IDE version. I've verified with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 available at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and with the latest Tomcat 9 version available at the moment (9.0.0.M26) and it works fine:

[image: Tomcat 9]

[image: Tomcat structure]

In your specific case IntelliJ IDEA was not able to read the files from the server installation directory because the user IDE was running from had no any permissions to the server installation directory. For development purposes it's enough to just download and unpack the server distribution into your home directory without changing any permissions for this directory. This way IDE will be able to read the files and use this installation.

Creating a separate user and limiting the permissions as [described in the guide you've followed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)  is only needed for the production servers that are open to public. It's a good security measure to limit the possible harm to the system in case the server is compromised or any security vulnerability is found in the JVM, the app server or your application running on this server.

Comment: I downloaded the tar.gz from the official Apache tomcat site

Comment: Do you use current IntelliJ IDEA version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html?

Comment: Yes I do, v 2017.2.1 for Intellij and  9.0.0M26 for Tomcat as you mentioned

Comment: Did you download `apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26.tar.gz` file? Did you unpack it using `tar -xzvf apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26.tar.gz` into the new empty directory? Please provide the output of `ls -lR /opt/tomcat`. Does IntelliJ IDEA have the permissions to read and execute in this directory?

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) is the tutorial I used to install Tomcat on my PC. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/TWJ6I) is the output of `ls -lR opt/tomcat` . I don't know if IntelliJ IDEA has the permissions necesary, and I don't know how to change them.

Comment: You've set the permissions so that your current user IntelliJ IDEA is running under cannot read any files in `/opt/tomcat`. See [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) for details. You need to give `read` permission to `others` for all the files and folders recursively and also give `exec` (`x`) permission to `bin/*.sh files` using `chmod` command.

Comment: Saw the article, couldn't change permissions under `opt/` folder. Anyway, I moved the `opt/tomcat/` directory to `home/paske/prog/devel` where it has [full permissions](http://imgur.com/a/y9AZi)  and I still get the same [error](http://imgur.com/a/pCv34).

Comment: Make a fresh unpack without changing the permissions.

Comment: I have done that. There's also another thing I don't understand: why do you have to initialize a `tomcat` user? I came across the same procedure when installing Jetty, for example.

Comment: This is the common security measure on Unix. If your app server (or any service in general) allows public access and is compromised, attacker would not be able to do a lot of harm to the system since he'll be able to perform the actions only with the limited permissions of the `tomcat` or `jetty` user which usually has login shell disabled and cannot modify any system critical files. If you are using the app server for the development purposes and it's not open to public, you don't need to create a separate user to run the server.

Comment: I've updated the answer to mention all the possible cases for this problem, including your very specific case. Please feel free to accept it: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:
xxx@yyyyyyy:cd  /opt/tomcat
xxx@yyyyyyy:/opt/tomcat$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./

Comment: Although this will resolve permission issues, it is not recommended that you set your entire tomcat directory to be this open. This is particularly insecure.